# svn - checkout error from Kuali Student

Tags: svn, kuali

I'm installing the Kuali Student Curriculum Management system on my PC. I've installed and set up all the prerequisites like maven, oracle, svn etc.

but when I load the kuali student bundled data as it says  [HERE.](https://wiki.kuali.org/display/STUDENTDOC/KS+Curriculum+Management+2.0+QuickStart+Installation+Guide#KSCurriculumManagement2.0QuickStartInstallationGuide-2.SetUptheDatabase)

I execute this command

```
svn co http://svn.kuali.org/repos/student/enrollment/ks-deployments/tags/ks-deployments-2.0.3-cm/ks-cfg-dbs/
```

I get this error

```
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://svn.kuali.org/rep
os/student/enrollment/ks-deployments/tags/ks-deployments-2.0.3-cm/ks-cfg-dbs'
svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'http://svn.kuali.org/repos/student/enrollment/ks-deplo
yments/tags/ks-deployments-2.0.3-cm/ks-cfg-dbs': Could not resolve hostname `svn
.kuali.org': The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was
found.
```

Please tell me how to correctly checkout from the Kuali Database. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it was a temporary problem.  I just ran the command you gave and successfully checked out revision 77743